# Python3.8 signXml future error during pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Running `pip install -r ./requirements` fails for `signXMl` module. Where pip is there in a VENV.

- Python version: 3.8.
- OS: MAC OS, python installation using brew.

Error:

```
 Using cached future-0.18.1.tar.gz (828 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/rahulroy/Desktop/work/data_new/data/venv/bin/python3.8 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/c3/vl0yxxj17fvbwkh1msldlhnc0000gn/T/pip-install-4_opjnck/future_29cfb8bb91d24ea5b8bad3f63de44251/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/c3/vl0yxxj17fvbwkh1msldlhnc0000gn/T/pip-install-4_opjnck/future_29cfb8bb91d24ea5b8bad3f63de44251/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/c3/vl0yxxj17fvbwkh1msldlhnc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lflwd8df
         cwd: /private/var/folders/c3/vl0yxxj17fvbwkh1msldlhnc0000gn/T/pip-install-4_opjnck/future_29cfb8bb91d24ea5b8bad3f63de44251/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/rahulroy/Desktop/work/data_new/data-gateway/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from fnmatch import fnmatchcase
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/fnmatch.py", line 14, in <module>
        import re
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 127, in <module>
        import functools
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 18, in <module>
        from collections import namedtuple
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
      File "/private/var/folders/c3/vl0yxxj17fvbwkh1msldlhnc0000gn/T/pip-install-4_opjnck/future_29cfb8bb91d24ea5b8bad3f63de44251/src/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
    ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
    --------------------------------
```

Which ultimately fails with this error:

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of alembic to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install signxml because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    eight 1.0.1 depends on future<0.19 and >=0.16
    eight 1.0.0 depends on future<0.19 and >=0.16
    eight 0.4.2 depends on future<0.17 and >=0.16

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
```

Parts of `requirements.txt`

> ```
> s3transfer==0.3.3
> signxml==2.8.2
> six==1.15.0
> soupsieve==2.2.1
> SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
> toml==0.10.1
> urllib3==1.25.10
> validators==0.18.2
> virtualenv==20.0.30
> Werkzeug==1.0.1
> xmltodict==0.12.0
> yapf==0.30.0
> zipfile38==0.0.3
> ```

The pip logs before the error:

```
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in
> ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.0.4->-r
> requirements.txt (line 41)) (56.0.0) Collecting macholib>=1.8   Using
> cached macholib-1.15.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB) Collecting
> eight<2,>=0.4.2   Using cached eight-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10
> kB) Collecting pyopenssl   Using cached
> pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB) Collecting
> decorator>=3.4.0   Using cached decorator-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.1
> kB) Collecting future<0.19,>=0.16   Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz
> (829 kB)
```

How can I resolve this error?